# Enable visual-line-mode and org-indent-mode when opening org files

Tags: org-mode, init-file

I'm new to emacs, org-mode. I have an org file which, every time I open, I have to enable the minor modes: `visual-line-mode` and `org-indent-mode` by hand using the `M-x` command.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058963/how-do-i-associate-a-minor-mode-to-a-particular-file-or-a-set-of-files-based-on) in stackoverflow and tried the following code in my `.emacs` file only to see an error when emacs loads.

**Code**

```
(require 'org-mode)  
(defun turn-on-visual-line-mode () (visual-line-mode 1))  
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-visual-line-mode)
```

**Error**

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘c:/Users/Prasanna Rajaram/AppData/Roaming/.emacs’:

File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, org-mode

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I did not try the `org-indent-mode` as I did not know how to turn on multiple minor modes with `defun()`.

Comment: So get the full debug trace as stated in that message: *Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.* and let us know what that is. The culprit here is that you are doing `(require 'org-mode)` instead of `(require 'org)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The culprit here is that you are doing `(require 'org-mode)` instead of `(require 'org)`.

---

But here's an alternative way to enable the minor modes that you need for org files (below is tested to work in an `emacs -Q` session):

```el
;; `with-eval-after-load' macro was introduced in Emacs 24.x
;; In older Emacsen, you can do the same thing with `eval-after-load'
;; and '(progn ..) form.
(with-eval-after-load 'org       
  (setq org-startup-indented t) ; Enable `org-indent-mode' by default
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode))
```

---

**Recommendation**: You should not directly `require` a package (even though doing so will also work). Doing so will make emacs load that whole package at startup and could result in slower startup. Instead, you should allow the `org` package to get automatically loaded as configured in the package itself, and then do org-specific setup in the `with-eval-after-load` or `eval-after-load` form.

Comment: I also found another way of doing it on a per-file-basis only for indenting. `#+STARTUP: indent`